# Rule to check if a node has a translation?

Tags: rules, i18n-l10n

Just wondering if I can create a this rule:

1) check if a node (when viewed) has the translations for all enabled languages.

2) If the it doesn't, then create the translation (for all enabled languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box: no.

If you are willing to code, check the [rules API](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/7). It lets you add your own conditions and actions.

If you don't need any of the rules functionality you can of course just implement [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7).

Comment: thanks, I'll try with hooK_node_view. Which function should I use to create a node translation?

Comment: I will create a new question to accomplish with this.